# Alias domain to cloudfront without managing DNS in Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a website, accessible through Cloudfront, that a customer wants to alias their own domain to, so that theirdomain.com points to my distribution. I got the certificate and added the alternate domain in my Cloudfront distribution. Now, I need them to map their domain to my cloudfront distribution. In Route 53, you can simply create A and AAAA entries mapping to the cloudfront domain, but they don't use Route 53 so they can't do this (A/AAAA must be IP address). I considered making a hosted zone for their domain and having them set the name servers to those of my hosted zone, but they prefer to manage their own DNS records. Is there any way to have them alias their domain to my website without managing their DNS?